# How can I trigger Template#onRendered when Blaze reuses a template?

Tags: jquery-ui, meteor, meteor-blaze

How can I trigger Template#onRendered, or equivalent, when Blaze reuses a template?

I have a jQuery UI selectmenu widget based on a `<select>` element whose `<option>` children are created using `{{#each}}` (targeting a helper which draws on `Session` in order to get reactivity) and a Blaze template. I'm refreshing the selectmenu onRendered.

- The Blaze template is correct. ( `<option>{{text}}</option>` )
- Session is getting changed (checked with both `console.log()` and manually setting it in the browser console.
- Session reactivity, the helper, and `{{#each}}` are working (inspecting the hidden `<select>` reveals that its options have been correctly updated)

It's just that templates are getting reused, so although everything works fine as long as the `Session` options context changes to have more options (`onRendered()` gets called after the new template instance is created), the jQuery UI selectmenu is inaccurate (not up to date with the current state of the context) if the `Session` options context changes to have the same or fewer options (fewer options only calls `onDestroyed()` and same number of options doesn't even do that).

Answer (score 0):

Solution: `Tracker.afterFlush(callback)` used inside the helper (which *is* getting called every time I expected) instead of Tempate.on_[anything]_().

https://docs.meteor.com/api/tracker.html#Tracker-afterFlush

e.g.

```
myContextOptionsHelper: function () {
  let context = Session.get('myContext');
  let contextOptions = app.client.tempdata.contextOptions[context];
  Tracker.afterFlush(() => {
    if ($('#mySelectmenu').is(':ui-selectmenu')) {
      $('#mySelectmenu').selectmenu('refresh');
    }
  });
  return contextOptions;
}
```